# Cordova can't find JDK

Tags: javascript, java, android, cordova

Y'all!

I'm trying to build an app with Cordova, but I keep getting this error:

> Android Studio project detected
>   Failed to run "javac -version", make sure that you have a JDK installed.
>   Your JAVA_HOME is invalid: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin

I've installed Java SDK again, and I've set Environment Variable by hand, still no can do :( 
Can someone help me please?

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Try removing the `\bin` from the JAVA_HOME path